# Error when using target.row in a vba module

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating an excel 2007 application which uses the exact same VBA code to force uppercase letters in 2 columns. This code is used in 8 different worksheets. I tried to create a subroutine in a module so that I can call the subroutine under each of the 8 worksheets but it isn't working.

When I added the following code directly under each worksheet it worked:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim TargetRowNumber  As Integer
Dim targetColumnNumber As Integer

If (Target.Row >= 6 And Target.Row <= 500) Then

    If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("F6:F500")) Is Nothing) Then
      If Target.Column = 6 Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Range("$F" & Target.Row).Value = UCase(Range("$F" & Target.Row).Value)
       Application.EnableEvents = True
      End If
    End If

    If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("K6:K500")) Is Nothing) Then
      If Target.Column = 11 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("$K" & Target.Row).Value = UCase(Range("$K" & Target.Row).Value)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
      End If
    End If

end if

end sub
```

But if I create a module with the same code and try to call the subroutine under each of the worksheets I get the following error:  Run-time error '424':  Object required.

Code in Module:

```
Sub convert_upper()
Dim TargetRowNumber  As Integer
Dim targetColumnNumber As Integer

If (Target.Row >= 6 And Target.Row <= 500) Then

    If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("F6:F500")) Is Nothing) Then
      If Target.Column = 6 Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Range("$F" & Target.Row).Value = UCase(Range("$F" & Target.Row).Value)
       Application.EnableEvents = True
      End If
    End If

    If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("K6:K500")) Is Nothing) Then
      If Target.Column = 11 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("$K" & Target.Row).Value = UCase(Range("$K" & Target.Row).Value)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
      End If
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Code under each worksheet to call the subroutine:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   convert_upper

End Sub
```

This is the first time that I have tried to program in vba.  I have tried to find a solution online without success.  I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Code included, reasonable explanation, has looked elsewhere. Seems pretty quality for a first question to me. Care to explain?

Comment: Question is of good quality.

Answer (score 4):

Chris has a good answer to get your individual event subroutines working.

However, a simpler way would be to use the Workbook-level `SheetChange` event. This works the same as a sheet-level event, except that it's triggered every time any sheet in a workbook is changed. Its arguments include `Sh` in addition to `Target`, so that you can test the which sheet triggered the event.  You'll want to do this, assuming you don't want every sheet in the workbook to trigger the event.

Here's some code I think will work for you. I've also tightened up your logic some. Paste it into your workbook's `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim RangeToUpper As Excel.Range
Dim AreaToUpper As Excel.Range

Select Case Sh.Name
Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
    If (Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("F6:F500")) Is Nothing) Or _
       Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("K6:K500")) Is Nothing Then
        Set RangeToUpper = Intersect(Target, Union(Sh.Range("F6:F500"), Sh.Range("K6:K500")))
        On Error GoTo Err_Handler
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each AreaToUpper In RangeToUpper.Areas
            AreaToUpper.Value = UCase(AreaToUpper.Value)
        Next AreaToUpper
    End If
End Select

Err_Handler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to think about `Variable Scope`

Change your `Sub` declaration to

```
Sub convert_upper(Target as Range)
```

And call it as

```
convert_upper Target
```

You will also need to qualify the `Range` references in your common `Sub` (otherwise the code refers to the `ActiveSheet`).  Eg (apply to all uses of `Range`)

```
With Target.Parent
    .Range("$F" & Target.Row).Value = UCase(.Range("$F" & Target.Row).Value)
End With
```